# Why is this code not working? I should be separating values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, scientific-computing

I have a large CSV file that I am trying to make into smaller sub-lists.

The only problem is that it is not doing what it should be... or at the very least separates data properly with only some stuff being correctly separated

My problem: I have a CSV file that has data that goes between 90 to 3 meters deep, and that data will go back and forth like so. I am using the newest python.

Everytime the number increases again, I want to separate it.

ex. (depth) 88, 77, 50, 20, 5, 90, 76, 54, 34, 15, 8, 4, 81, 74, 62,51, 49, 30, 22, 10, 8... and so on. It keeps going between 90 to 3, and so on.

What I want to do is to separate the data each time it goes between 90 and 3. Once it is separated I want to take the last and first values in that list. Like so ex. 88, 77, 50, 20, 5 (separate here), 90, 76, 54, 34, 15, 8, 4 (separate here) 81, 74, 62,51, 49, 30, 22, 10, 8 separate here)... and so on.

Here is my code:

```
#two sets of data that you test with.
m = ['9.90203', '9.79947', '9.66876', '9.54503', '9.42167', '9.2977', '9.17321', '9.05162', '8.11487', '8.038', '7.96111', '7.85746', '7.72701', '7.59709', '7.46781', '7.34127', '7.21842', '7.09548', '6.96798', '6.57355', '6.444', '6.32245', '6.23818', '6.15369', '6.04973', '4.63443', '4.49823', '4.36232', '4.21442', '4.0642', '26.5645', '26.4945', '26.4232', '26.3592', '26.2948', '23.418', '23.3667', '23.2756', '23.1856', '22.1849', '22.0822', '22.0191', '21.9671', '21.9154', '21.8641', '20.436', '20.3865', '20.3364', '20.2083', '20.0915', '19.9758', '19.8601', '19.7446', '19.6317', '18.1383', '17.9834', '17.8271', '17.7529', '17.6949', '17.6317', '17.5675', '17.4362', '16.581', '16.4745', '16.378', '16.2562', '16.1471', '16.0222', '15.89', '14.9752', '14.8725', '14.7666', '14.6234', '14.469', '14.3148', '13.7696', '13.6465', '13.5363', '13.4712', '13.4069', '13.3421', '13.2732', '13.1375', '13.0014', '12.4809', '12.3585', '12.2339', '12.121', '12.0116', '11.901', '11.7906', '11.6645', '11.5278', '11.3931', '11.2551', '11.1211', '10.993', '10.8501', '10.7205', '10.6026', '10.4992', '10.3952']
l = ['8.18142', '8.11846', '8.05988', '59.4627', '59.3455', '59.2296', '58.4541', '58.3302', '58.2265', '58.1239', '58.0314', '57.9405', '57.8496', '57.7514', '57.6746', '57.6098', '57.5414', '57.4722', '57.3517', '57.2151', '57.0934', '56.9704', '56.8361', '56.6993', '56.564', '56.4287', '56.3106', '56.2', '56.0877', '55.9782', '55.8869', '55.8223', '55.7578', '55.6933', '55.605', '55.4949', '55.3858', '55.2761', '55.1612', '55.0097', '54.8786', '54.7385', '54.6315', '54.5282', '54.4292', '54.327', '54.2217', '54.1127', '54.0037', '53.8938', '53.7695', '53.6271', '53.4857', '53.3437', '53.2254', '53.1712', '53.12', '53.0679', '53.0102', '52.9126', '52.8148', '52.7182', '52.6207', '52.491', '52.3561', '52.2267', '52.0908', '51.9405', '51.7786', '51.6421', '51.5043', '51.4063', '51.3087', '51.2117', '51.1141', '51.0304', '50.9446', '50.8577', '50.7744', '50.6716', '50.5655', '50.4625', '50.3598', '50.2569', '50.153', '50.0494', '49.9461', '49.8308', '49.7058', '49.582', '49.4583', '49.3473', '49.251', '49.1533', '49.0561', '48.953', '48.83', '48.7064', '48.5812', '48.4635', '48.3852', '48.2998', '48.2219', '48.1428', '48.0327', '47.9221', '47.8114', '47.7007', '47.5964', '47.4905', '47.3875', '47.2847', '47.1595', '47.0424', '46.9264']

group =0
temp = []
splited_list = {}
lengh = len(l)

for i in range(lengh):
    if not i == lengh-1:
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            temp.append(l[i])
        else:
            temp.append(l[i])
            group +=1
            splited_list.update({str(group):temp})
            temp = []
    else:
        if l[i] < l[-2]:
           temp.append(l[i])
           group +=1
           splited_list.update({str(group):temp})
           break
        else:
            group +=1
            splited_list.update({str(group):[l[i]]})
            break

print (splited_list)
```

Here is my output:

> {'1': ['8.18142', '8.11846', '8.05988', '59.4627', '59.3455', '59.2296', '58.4541', '58.3302', '58.2265', '58.1239', '58.0314', '57.9405', '57.8496', '57.7514', '57.6746', '57.6098', '57.5414', '57.4722', '57.3517', '57.2151', '57.0934', '56.9704', '56.8361', '56.6993', '56.564', '56.4287', '56.3106', '56.2', '56.0877', '55.9782', '55.8869', '55.8223', '55.7578', '55.6933', '55.605', '55.4949', '55.3858', '55.2761', '55.1612', '55.0097', '54.8786', '54.7385', '54.6315', '54.5282', '54.4292', '54.327', '54.2217', '54.1127', '54.0037', '53.8938', '53.7695', '53.6271', '53.4857', '53.3437', '53.2254', '53.1712', '53.12', '53.0679', '53.0102', '52.9126', '52.8148', '52.7182', '52.6207', '52.491', '52.3561', '52.2267', '52.0908', '51.9405', '51.7786', '51.6421', '51.5043', '51.4063', '51.3087', '51.2117', '51.1141', '51.0304', '50.9446', '50.8577', '50.7744', '50.6716', '50.5655', '50.4625', '50.3598', '50.2569', '50.153', '50.0494', '49.9461', '49.8308', '49.7058', '49.582', '49.4583', '49.3473', '49.251', '49.1533', '49.0561', '48.953', '48.83', '48.7064', '48.5812', '48.4635', '48.3852', '48.2998', '48.2219', '48.1428', '48.0327', '47.9221', '47.8114', '47.7007', '47.5964', '47.4905', '47.3875', '47.2847', '47.1595', '47.0424', '46.9264']}

Here is my desired output:

> {'1': ['8.18142', '8.11846', '8.05988'], '2': ['59.4627', '59.3455', '59.2296', '58.4541', '58.3302', '58.2265', '58.1239', '58.0314', '57.9405', '57.8496', '57.7514', '57.6746', '57.6098', '57.5414', '57.4722', '57.3517', '57.2151', '57.0934', '56.9704', '56.8361', '56.6993', '56.564', '56.4287', '56.3106', '56.2', '56.0877', '55.9782', '55.8869', '55.8223', '55.7578', '55.6933', '55.605', '55.4949', '55.3858', '55.2761', '55.1612', '55.0097', '54.8786', '54.7385', '54.6315', '54.5282', '54.4292', '54.327', '54.2217', '54.1127', '54.0037', '53.8938', '53.7695', '53.6271', '53.4857', '53.3437', '53.2254', '53.1712', '53.12', '53.0679', '53.0102', '52.9126', '52.8148', '52.7182', '52.6207', '52.491', '52.3561', '52.2267', '52.0908', '51.9405', '51.7786', '51.6421', '51.5043', '51.4063', '51.3087', '51.2117', '51.1141', '51.0304', '50.9446', '50.8577', '50.7744', '50.6716', '50.5655', '50.4625', '50.3598', '50.2569', '50.153', '50.0494', '49.9461', '49.8308', '49.7058', '49.582', '49.4583', '49.3473', '49.251', '49.1533', '49.0561', '48.953', '48.83', '48.7064', '48.5812', '48.4635', '48.3852', '48.2998', '48.2219', '48.1428', '48.0327', '47.9221', '47.8114', '47.7007', '47.5964', '47.4905', '47.3875', '47.2847', '47.1595', '47.0424', '46.9264']}

Comment: 1. Are you doing anything with `m`? 2.  `'8.05988'` is bigger than `'59.4627'` because `'8'` comes after `'5'`, as you are comparing strings. 3. Is each row supposed to be a separate dictionary? 4. Why use a dictionary if the keys will just be a simple range of integers?

Comment: 1. m is another set of test values

Comment: 2. Should I compare float then? 3. Im making a dictionary, and then later on making a bunch of lists from the values in each key ( not shown here). 4. I am not sure... I am new to coding.

Comment: @Adam are you sure you are unable to come up with a better question title than this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating this. Remember that to do the comparison you want to convert the strings into floats first. Also, there's no need to reference each point by its index; you can just iterate over the `list` object directly. 
Also, as pointed out above, having a dictionary keyed by integers is a little unusual, consider using a list of lists instead.

```
points = ['9.90203', '9.79947', '9.66876', '9.54503', '9.42167', '9.2977', '9.17321', '9.05162', '8.11487', '8.038',
          '7.96111', '7.85746', '7.72701', '7.59709', '7.46781', '7.34127', '7.21842', '7.09548', '6.96798', '6.57355',
          '6.444', '6.32245', '6.23818', '6.15369', '6.04973', '4.63443', '4.49823', '4.36232', '4.21442', '4.0642',
          '26.5645', '26.4945', '26.4232', '26.3592', '26.2948', '23.418', '23.3667', '23.2756', '23.1856', '22.1849',
          '22.0822', '22.0191', '21.9671', '21.9154', '21.8641', '20.436', '20.3865', '20.3364', '20.2083', '20.0915',
          '19.9758', '19.8601', '19.7446', '19.6317', '18.1383', '17.9834', '17.8271', '17.7529', '17.6949', '17.6317',
          '17.5675', '17.4362', '16.581', '16.4745', '16.378', '16.2562', '16.1471', '16.0222', '15.89', '14.9752',
          '14.8725', '14.7666', '14.6234', '14.469', '14.3148', '13.7696', '13.6465', '13.5363', '13.4712', '13.4069',
          '13.3421', '13.2732', '13.1375', '13.0014', '12.4809', '12.3585', '12.2339', '12.121', '12.0116', '11.901',
          '11.7906', '11.6645', '11.5278', '11.3931', '11.2551', '11.1211', '10.993', '10.8501', '10.7205', '10.6026',
          '10.4992', '10.3952']

data = dict()
idx = 1
last_point = float(points[0])
subset = [points[0]]
for point in points[1:]:
    num_point = float(point)
    if num_point > last_point:
        data[idx] = subset
        subset = [point]
        idx += 1
    else:
        subset.append(point)
    last_point = num_point

data[idx] = subset
```

Comment: How would you make that back into a dictionary like in my answer? It is just what I need to keep it as so I can use it later like that.

Comment: That is a dictionary. I didn't change it. I just suggested you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
l = map(float, l)
results = [[ l[0] ]]

for i in l[1:]:
    if i>results[-1][-1]:
        results.append([i])
    else:
        results[-1].append(i)
```

This is going to give you a list of lists. If you really want the dictionary, you can try:

```
resultsDict = {i:m for i, m in enumerate(results)}
```

or to shorten it a little bit:

```
resultsDict = dict(enumerate(results))
```

I like the previous one better because it is a little more readable ...

If you really need to keep the strings, you may change the comparison `i>results[-1][-1]` to `float(i)>float(results[-1][-1])`, and get rid of the initial `map`.